# How can I install additional audio/video codecs on Android?

Tags: audio, video, media-player, system

Does android separate the module between video player and video codec? If so, how do we install more codec to the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video codecs are limited to what is supported by the device. This suggests that the codecs are in firmware and not software codecs like you are used to on the computer. This means you will probably need to use something like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert your videos to the phone. Unless there are in the h264 or 3GP formats that all android phones support.

Reference: [Act1 Video Player FAQ](http://www.hyperaware.com/android/video-player/video-on-android.html#formats)

Comment: not every H.264 media android support, it depend on the profile level, AFAIK my G1 only support baseline level, since I tried to encode a video using x264 using main profile the device can't handle it.

Comment: good point, there are many ways to encode h264 just like for DivX/XviD. It seems that only baseline is universally supported.

Comment: if the codecs are firmware how do some applications do that ? i am trying to play Quick time video and my default application cant play him but mx player  for example can ...